# How can i delete duplicate rows but keep values from specific cells in the row?

Tags: ms-office

you can see in the image below there are 5 duplicate rows and what i want to do is to delete all the duplicate rows  expect the game column and the first row and imagine there are many sets like this in the sheet so how can I do this is in one go. Thanks in advance.

[image: duplicate rows]

Comment: Sorry, but I can’t see any duplicate rows. All rows are unique and none of them is a duplicate of another.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! I have to agree with the comment as technically there are no duplicate rows. Additionally, just how do propose deleting a row yet maintaining certain data? If you delete a row, it's deleted! Where do you want to put the data you don't want deleted? Maybe what you really want it not to actual delete a row, as you've stated, but clear all the cells of the data you do not want to retain? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your question so it actually reflect what it is you are really wanting to do.

Comment: That said, I'd suggest a good way to manipulate spreadsheet _data_, assuming it does not contain any formulas, is to export it as an, e.g., **CSV** file and then use e.g. `awk`, or other _command line utilities_ to manipulate the _data_.

Comment: Microsoft Excel has feature called PivotTable which is handy in filtering, grouping, slicing, displaying, calculating etc of underlying data without need to delete rows.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you actually need to use database software. ([See link for Microsoft Access alternatives for Mac](https://machow2.com/microsoft-access-mac-open-databases/).) You should be able to export your spreadsheet directly into the program and that will allow you to manipulate and control the information more granularly.

Otherwise, the closest thing I could find to what you're trying to accomplish is by using Categories in Apple's Numbers.

[image: Number Category example.]

If you need to stick to Excel that's probably going to take some incredibly complex strategies (custom filters, tables, data linking, multiple workbooks, etc.)